# Rails Handling Exceptions based on constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make custom Errors pages depending on where the user is in the app — whether they are on the Marketing website (e.g `example.com/about`, on a Store site (e.g `my-store.example.com`), or on the Store Admin panel (e.g `my-store.example.com/admin`). Logically, on the Store site we want to show a `404` page branded to the Store, and on the Admin panel we want to show a different `404` for the system.

Currently, I can not differentiate between the Store site `my-store.example.com/404` path, and the `my-store.example.com/admin/404` path. Is there a way to rescue exceptions under a certain path, specifically, exceptions that include `admin/*` in the request?

```
# application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# Routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
  get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
  get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"

  root "home#index"
  
  constraints(::Constraints::CustomDomainConstrainer) do
    scope module: :store do
      get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
      get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
      get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"
    
      root to: "home#index", as: :storefront
    end

    scope module: "admin" do
      get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
      get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
      get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"
    end
  end
end

module Constraints
  class CustomDomainConstrainer
    # Implement the .matches? method and pass in the request object
    def self.matches?(request)
      matching_site?(request)
    end

    def self.matching_site?(request)
      # Handle the case of the user's domain being either
      # www. or a root domain with one query
      if request.subdomain == 'www'
        req = request.host[4..-1]
      else
        req = request.host
      end

      case req
      when Account.where(subdomain: request.subdomain).any? || Account.includes(:pages_domains).where(pages_domains: {domain: request.domain}).any?
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For context, the above routes map to the following controllers,

1. `errors#not_found`
2. `store/errors#not_found`
3. `admin/errors#not_found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question only makes sense when using `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` in `config/application.rb`.  That isn't mentioned, but it's the only mechanism that leads to this routes.rb functioning as an exception renderer.

Assuming which, I see three problems:

1. The default error paths come first in the routes.rb, so Rails just uses those. It never even gets to the constrained section.  Place the unconstrained routes *last*.
2. Rails's default exception-handling middleware won't redispatch your admin-module errors to `admin/404` et al. They still go to `/404`.
3. The `scope module:` declarations don't create a path prefix, so they'll both match `/404`.  When Rails gets to the constrained section, the first one there wins, i.e. the store one.

If you want those dispatched differently, you'll need an extra separate constraint to recognise the *original* path.  Fortunately, Action Dispatch's exception middleware provides this, when handing off to an exception app.  But again, this has to go in front of any less constrained routes.

You might end up with something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(::Constraints::CustomDomainConstrainer) do
    scope module: :admin, constraints: ->(req) { req.original_fullpath.starts_with?('/admin/') } do
      get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
      get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
      get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"
    end

    scope module: :store do
      get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
      get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
      get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"
    
      root to: "home#index", as: :storefront
    end
  end

  get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
  get "/422", to: "errors#unacceptable"
  get "/500", to: "errors#internal_error"

  root "home#index"
end
```

For clarity, I'd probably then hoist the inline constraint up into a class.

Comment: Thanks @inopinatus, you're correct with regards to `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` in `config/application.rb` being an important mechanism that is unmentioned. For future context, I've updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [rescue_from](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) and put in the respective controllers. Presumably you have a common base controller for both namespaces (e.g. `ApplicationController` and `Admin::ApplicationController` or something like that). That's where you'd put the `rescue_from`.

Basic example:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404

  # ...

  private

  def render_404
    render 'errors/not_found'
  end
end
```

```rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404

  # ...

  private

  def render_404
    render 'admin/errors/not_found'
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not actually differentiate between the Store site `my-store.example.com/404` path, and the `my-store.example.com/admin/404` path. Is there a way to rescue exceptions under a certain path, specifically, exceptions that include `admin/*` in the request?

Answer (score -1):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404

  private

  def render_404
    if request.path.starts_with?('/admin')
      render 'admin_404'
    else
      render 'regular_404'
    end
  end
end
```